# Looping through validation data received from Ajax in laravel controller

Tags: php, json, ajax, laravel

I am sending a json request through Ajax, this request contains multiple objects,I am trying to find a way to validate the request to fail if at least one particular attribute fails the rule(min 5 characters in "value"); but dosent seems to work, can anyone help ?
I tried to loop data , I feel I am close but still dosent work.

```
my Ajax:
-------    
< script >
  function ajaxUpdate() {
    var formdata = document.getElementsByTagName('input'); 
    var formT = [].map.call(formdata, function(input) {

      if (input.style.textDecoration === "line-through") {
        input['completed'] = "1"; //add key value pairs
      } else {
        input['completed'] = "0"; //add key value pairs
      }
      return {
        'value': input.value,
        'id': input.id,
        'completed': input.completed
      }; //determine what keys to show.
    });

    formT.shift(); // Removes the first element from an array, because it contains token
    formT = formT.filter(function(e) {
      return e != null; //remove null elements.
    });

    $.ajaxSetup({
      headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      }
    });
    // e.preventDefault();


    $.ajax({
      url: "/updateAddTask",
      dataType: "json",
      contentType: "application/json",
      data: {
        objJSON: JSON.stringify(formT),
      },

      success: function(response) {

        if ($.isEmptyObject(response.error)) {

          if (response.success === true) {
            successSweetAlert();
          } else {
            alert(JSON.stringify(response.errors.value.toString()));
          }

        }
      },
      // location.reload();
    })
  } 
</script>



My controller:
--------------

  public function loopData(Array $data)
{
    foreach ($data  as $key => $jsons) {
        foreach ($jsons as $key1 => $value) {
            return $jsons;
        }
    }
}
   
  public function ajaxUpdateTasks(Request $request)

    {
        $data = json_decode($request->objJSON, true);//this will give an array of all the input elements

// dd($data);//output is below:
// array:3 [
//  0 => array:3 [
//    "value" => "kilo"
//    "id" => "55"
//    "completed" => "0"
//  ]
//  1 => array:3 [
//    "value" => "new123"
//    "id" => "793"
//    "completed" => "1"
//  ]
//  2 => array:3 [
//    "value" => "ef4"
//    "id" => "794"
//    "completed" => "0"
//  ]
//]


        $rules = [
            'value' => 'required|max:255|min:5', //value is
        ];


        $messages = [
            'value.max' => 'Todo title should be less than 255 characters',
            'value.min' => 'Todo title should be more than 4 characters'
        ];


        $validator = Validator::make($this->loopData($data),$rules, $messages);// ?????

        if ($validator->fails()) {

            $errors = $validator->getMessageBag()->toArray();
            $result = ['success' => false, 'errors' => $errors];
            return response()->json($result);
        } else {
            $result = ['success' => true, 'errors' => null];

            $count = count(json_decode($request->objJSON, true));
            $id = json_decode($request->objJSON, true)[0] ['id'];
            $value = json_decode($request->objJSON, true)[0] ['value'];
            $completed = json_decode($request->objJSON, true)[0] ['completed'];
            
            
            -----remaining of the code --------
    }
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I think it will help https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#validating-arrays

Comment: I tried the following:       $validator=Validator::make($data, [
            "objJSON"=> 'array',
           "objJSON.value"=> 'min:5',
           ]); but still didnt work.

Comment: Since you have to decode your json, it is not sent correctly you are sending as a string which is wrong

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by simply changing rules and messages: $rules = [ " *.value" => 'min:4', ]; $messages = [ " *.value.max" => 'Todo title should be less than 255 characters', " *.value.min" => 'Text should be more than 4 characters' ]; $validator=Validator::make($data, $rules,$messages);